# how i can make connect between php 5 and oracle 10g

Tags: php, oracle

how i can make connect between php 5 and oracle 10g and what should i set in php.ini?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5365004/configure-php-with-oracle

Comment: Did you already read and try http://php.net/manual/en/oci8.setup.php ?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with the database, but Oracle have a very extensive [FAQ on PHP and Oracle](http://wiki.oracle.com/page/PHP+Oracle+FAQ):

> **OCI8 extension: Oracle Call Interface functions**
>
> OCI8 is the recommended PHP driver for Oracle. In use at many high profile sites, it provides an easy to use, reliable interface for creating high performance web applications. [...]
>
> **PDO_OCI extension: "PHP Data Object" functions**
>
> PDO_OCI is the Oracle driver for the PDO data abstraction interface in PHP. While PDO is gaining a little popularity, PDO_OCI isn't as mature as OCI8 and doesn't support some of the features that OCI8 does.[...]
>
> **ORA extension: Oracle functions**
>
> The obsolete ORA extension is no longer included in PHP distributions. It had limited functionality and was implemented using a now obsolete API to the Oracle database.

So it looks like OCI8 is your best bet. See the PHP manual [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.oci8.php).

Comment: Lots of additional resources at OTN: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/php/whatsnew/index.html and http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/php/underground-php-oracle-manual-098250.html